# Approximate an inner class within an interface?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control

This is mainly for neatness in a WPF project using Dependency Injection

In Java I can do the following:

```
public interface MyInjectable
{
    void ExampleMethod();

    public class Impl : MyInjectable
    {
        void ExampleMethod()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Which is nice when using DI frameworks, as you call the inner class MyInjectable.Impl() to instatiate the class, and just write MyInjectable elsewhere.

In C# I must do this:

```
public interface IMyInjectable
{
    void ExampleMethod();
}

public class MyInjectable: IMyInjectable
{
    void ExampleMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

IE I have to name the class something unique and a separate interface. Is there a better way to do this, or any workaround to get something that approximates an inner Impl class inside an interface?

Comment: c# interfaces can not contain implementation. That said. Im failing to see what the real advantages are, quite honestly. What is troubling you about the lack of this feature in c#? Having to think of a new unique class name? That seems a rather poor reason for a language feature.

Comment: That's fair enough, thanks. My reason is that it's going to appear across the code base for a couple of projects, so I wanted to know if there is a trick I wasn't aware of - I've come across this pattern a bit in java progs I've seen. I agree it's not that big a deal

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there's no 'better' way to address this in C#. Usually, because of the little remnant of Hungarian notation in C#, interfaces are, like in the OP, usually prefixed with `I` (e.g. `IMyInjectable`), which leaves free the unprefixed name (e.g. `MyInjectable`) for an implementation.

If, however, the code mostly consists of `IFoo`/`Foo` pairs, it's most likely violating the [Reused Abstractions Principle](http://codemanship.co.uk/parlezuml/blog/?postid=934). If possible, reconsider the application architecture to address that code smell.